# On AppInvites for iOS, how is a match performed between an invite and an installation?

Tags: ios, google-app-invites

On the site, it says that in the scenario where the app is not installed, after installing and launching the app it is possible that the App Invites SDK will indicate a "weak match for a deeplink".

What does that mean?

Is it based on the user's I sent the invite to and the google user logged in on the device that received the invite?

If not, how is a match performed on iOS after installing and launching the app?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Apple's IDFA the install can be attributed to where(which user) it came from.

[IDFA and How to avoid getting your app rejected](http://www.inmobi.com/blog/2014/05/06/idfa-and-how-to-avoid-getting-your-app-rejected-by-itunes)